# Library for numerical double integration in Java

Tags: library, java, numerical-analysis

Does there exist a Java library for evaluation of double integrals numerically using e.g. the multivariate Simpson's Rule? See [Horwitz 2001, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics 134 1–11](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-computational-and-applied-mathematics/vol/134).

I only require a 2D domain, i.e. double integrals, but for arbitrary integrands.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at this post that has a reply with a few suggestions. https://community.oracle.com/thread/1194156 as well as https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-write-a-Java-program-that-can-do-Integration